# Generalize User Environment

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to update code so that files can be located no matter what folder they reside in.

I have files I need from a particular folder called `DB Templates` but I need to adjust my code so that these files can be utilized whether this folder sits in Desktop or Documents, etc.

My current code is:

```vb
Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\DBTemplates\matrix.csv"
```

Comment: hi. u want to ask user where thr file is ? just use a FileDialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A Simple and fast way

You can use a `Function` like this to check if the file Exists:

```
Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim TestStr As String
    TestStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = "" Then
        FileExists = False
    Else
        FileExists = True
    End If
End Function
```

And at this point, you can simply try to load the file, like in this example:

```
desktopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\DBTemplates\matrix.csv"
documentsPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\DBTemplates\matrix.csv"

if FileExists(desktopPath) then loadFile(desktopPath)
if FileExists(documentsPath) then loadFile(documentsPath)
'Add any other Path you want to check...
```

---

#### Alternative Way

Using this method, you can search for your file and then load it.

```
Sub FindMyFile()
    Debug.Print Search(Environ("USERPROFILE"), "matrix.csv")
End Sub

Function Search(sPath As String, fileToFind As String) As String

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim mySubFolder As Folder
    Dim myFile As File

    Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)

    For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
            If myFile.Name = fileToFind Then
                Debug.Print myFile.Name & " in " & myFile.Path 'Or do whatever you want with the file
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Search = Search(mySubFolder.Path, fileToFind)
    Next

End Function
```

> **Note**: Please note that this method can take a **very long time** to find for your file. Use this only if there are no alternatives or choose a root directory that does not have many folders/files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help but this still seems too specific... is there a wildcard function to find the folder path just by the folder name?

Comment: @AmieJohnson Yes, there is an alternative way. It will search for your file in every directory from the root. Note that it will take some time to do that.

Comment: @AmieJohnson If you found this answer helpful, please upvote/accept it, so other can benefit from it. Thank you.